# How to make Irrlicht's collision animator two-way street

Tags: irrlicht

Using the default built-in collision animator of Irrlicht I have found out that it works only on one side of the polygons of my geometry.

I have used the following code:

```
selector = smgr->createOctreeTriangleSelector(
                q3node->getMesh(), q3node, 128);
        q3node->setTriangleSelector(selector);
ICameraSceneNode* camera =
        smgr->addCameraSceneNodeFPS(0, 100.0f, .3f, ID_IsNotPickable, 0, 0, true, 3.f);
ISceneNodeAnimator* anim = smgr->createCollisionResponseAnimator(
            selector, camera, core::vector3df(30,50,30),
            core::vector3df(0,-10,0), core::vector3df(0,30,0));
selector->drop();
camera->addAnimator(anim);
anim->drop();
```

Moreover I have noticed that the geometry is not textured on the other side.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of disabling the other side of the polygons is called `Backface Culling`

To disable it on your geometry do the following before performing any other actions:

```
q3node->setMaterialFlag(EMF_BACKFACE_CULLING, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, where should I put it exactly?

Comment: Before creating your selector

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you may make your geometry with normals on both sides. This would even make irrlicht do less computations.
No need to disable the blackface culling then.